# Groupid is failing to pass

Tags: asp.net

Server Error in '/ALOD' Application.

groupId must be greater than or equal to O

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: ALOD.Core.Utils.PreconditionException: groupId must be greater than or equal to O

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[PreconditionException: groupId must be greater than or equal to O]
ALOD.Core.Utils.Check.Require(Boolean assertion, String message) in C:\WorkSpace\ALODTESTOG\ALOD.Core\Utils\DesignByContract.cs:52
ALOD.Data.SRXDocumentStore.GetDocumentsByGroupId(Int64 groupId) in C:\WorkSpace\ALODTESTOG\ALOD.Data\SRXDocumentStore.cs:145
ALOD.Core.Domain.Modules.Lod.LineOfDuty_v2.ProcessDocuments(IDaoFactory daoFactory) in C:\WorkSpace\ALODTESTOG\ALOD.Core\Domain\Modules\Lod\LineOfDuty_v2.cs:202
ALOD.Core.Domain.Documents.WorkflowDocument..ctor(LineOfDuty LOD, Int32 DocStart, IDaoFactory factory) in C:\WorkSpace\ALODTESTOG\ALOD.Core\Domain\Documents\WorkflowDocument.cs:62
ALOD.Web.LOD.Secure_lod_Documents.GetDocuments() in C:\WorkSpace\ALODTESTOG\ALOD\Secure\lod\Documents.aspx.vb:205
ALOD.Web.LOD.Secure_lod_Documents.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\WorkSpace\ALODTESTOG\ALOD\Secure\lod\Documents.aspx.vb:186
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +154
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4082

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framew

I tried handling from the top up

By going to the points of interest

Could anyone give me any advice of how to go about doing this

I also checked my database there is no groupid of zero

So it leads to tell me that it’s error by not passing the groupid

Somehow even thoe when you sign into each account they have there groups assigned seeping on what organizations you are in and what’s level in the line of duty you are